# starting Tor browser (Windows 7 - 64 bit) - error message

Tags: configuration, windows

When launching the Tor browser.exe, the following error message pops up:

> Tor Browser does not have permission to access the profile. Please adjust your file system permissions and try again.

Any suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: Did you install the browser as the same user that you're trying to run it as? (Did you install it as the administrator?)

Comment: Extract the tor browser bundle into some other partition than C: drive(drive that has installed your os into ). then open tor. For example, extract into E:\tor

Comment: What is your OS exactly?
If its windows I suggest to use expert bundle and set socks to 127.0.0.1:9050 and I never used tor in Linux I should try it

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue after installing Tor Browser into "C:\Program Files\". The solution was to run Tor Browser as Administrator, due to write permissions into system protected folders like "Program Files".

Go to executable file (or shortcut that you use for running Tor Browser) Properties > Compatibility and tick "Run this program as administrator".

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You probably already know this, but running Tor Browser as administrator reduces the security of your system.

Comment: @Steve > Right, as any other vulnerable software out on Internet. :) It's up to him to take the chances. It is a solution however. I hope he will rather choose to install Tor Browser elsewhere, as Vishwa suggested.